# how do I specify zero fill for numpy savetxt output

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using numpy savetxt to create a csv file from a numpy array

My variables are....

```
columns = ['my_data']

my_data = numpy.array([850.62344
                      1133.23488
                      1230.32894
                      1468.23409
                      1345.63230
                        43.48530])
```

My savetxt function is.....

```
numpy.savetxt(outfile_path, my_data, fmt='%4.2f',
              delimiter='\t', header='\t'.join(columns), comments='')
```

The text file output looks like this.....

```
my_data
850.62
1133.24
1230.33
1468.23
1345.63
43.49
```

I want it to look like this....

```
my_data
0850.62
1133.24
1230.33
1468.23
1345.63
0043.49
```

So what I'm looking for is to zero fill the whole number part of the float to 4 for each data point and only have 2 decimal places.  How do I do this?

Comment: hey look at that, numpy.savetxt has an online help page: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html. And it says "0 : Left pad the number with zeros instead of space (see width)."

Comment: Oooo  good catch.  I did not see that.  I'll give it a try.